# JavaScript/Jquery in BlogSpot does not work in mobile browsers

Tags: javascript, jquery, blogger

My page in BlogSpot works fine except in the mobile browsers I've tried (only an old iPod touch and my Windows 8 Phone, so I'm not sure about others).

The page is [here](http://microinteriors.blogspot.com/p/pay-raise-calculator.html).

Basically, after pressing a button object, JQuery populates a DIV with an .html() function, making the DIV grow in size, and I think that's the problem.

I was wondering if there is any way to fix this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem here is that blogger loads different templates for mobile device and a PC. The PC version of your blog has all the necessary codes to run the function but the mobile template don't seem to have them.

Your script and the jQuery library doesn't load up in the mobile template, so you need to make some changes in your template to make it load on mobile browsers too. It's very simple, all you have to do is wrap the codes between

```
<b:if cond='data:blog.isMobile'></b:if>
```

And the scripts will be loaded in mobile templates too.

It must look like this

```
<b:if cond='data:blog.isMobile'>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

<script>
// your script
</script>
</b:if>
```

Place this anywhere template (best if near the original scripts) and save the template. And first check it on your PC by loading the mobile template of your blog, to do that just add `?m=1` at the end of your blog's URL.

Comment: Thanks, I'll give it a try tomorrow!

Comment: It looks like I needed to do this markup in the HTML template, and disable the mobile version, for this to work.  Not exactly what I was hoping for -- maybe Blogger will someday have Mobile template editing - but I learned a lot.  Thanks for your help.

Comment: The edits for mobile templates can be done from the single template editing option available in the template section. Mobile template codes are just inside special blogger conditional tag. @Dave you may remove the best answer mark to get a better answer which can help you more efficiently :)

Comment: Your answer is excellent, no need to change anything.  I'm fine with my lazy approach of disabling the mobile browser for now but when I have more time I'll follow your instructions.  I didn't know Blogger was so flexible.  Thanks again.

Answer (score 3):

As [@Deepak Kamat stated](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15858351/4933700).. it won't work even if you put the javascript code inside

`<b:if cond='data:blog.isMobile'></b:if>`

All you need to do is choose the right **mobile** template, in this case I believe you've made some changes on your **Desktop** template, so you must choose "Custom" from the mobile template drop down list

Comment: can you tell me that how i can use javascript in mobile mode?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, i tried to fix this then i found some steps to enable this on mobile mode
but when you put this script code in add gadget then for me it not worked
here is some step that i followed
- first i opened the theme and then click on ... menu choose edit html and finally put these below line of code and it worked. i posted some of picture hope it will be helped.

`<b:if cond='data:blog.isMobile'><script>console.log(&quot;Hello&quot;)</script></b:if>`

[image]
[image]

[image]

Comment: The tag is maybe necessary if you ONLY want a script to run on mobile. The problem, for me, is that I had a script that didn't show on mobile, so things wouldn't render correctly. This was solved by "Mobile Settings" in your image, and then switching mobile to the custom theme - the same theme as desktop.

Comment: i am now using angular in my blogspot you can check this link https://irobohawk.blogspot.com/